# Reading from a .xlsx file in Python (incorrect date and time formatting)

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

I'm trying to read a .xlsx from Python and I'm having a bit of trouble. I've tried different aproaches, but the one that worked the best was this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook('path')
sheet = workbook.active
print(sheet.cell(2, 1).value)
```

This is the file in question:

[image]

That print on the code prints ***"2021-03-10 00:00:00"***.

The code appears to be picking the data of the two columns appended together, but that isn' true. If I do ***sheet.cell(3, 1).value***, I still get the same value (I was expecting "2021-03-10 00:01:00"). Maybe the libray is detecting that as a date and giving me a custom formatted string. The position of the year, month and days is different and I always get that "00:00:00" after. My system is in English and I assume that file was made in a PT_br environment. Is that maybe something related to this?

If I do ***sheet.cell(3, 2).value***, I get "00:01:00" instead of "00:01".

I have tried to use .internal_value instead and I get the same results.
What I need is get the value as it seen on the file. Nothing less, nothing more.

Thanks!

Comment: in excel, 10/31/2021 00:00:00 is just the longer version of 10/31/2021. It's not appending things together, its just formatting it in a different way. In column b, it looks like your times aren't formatted using the "Time" format option in excel. I would highly recommend changing your excel to format them as a "time" if you wish to import this properly. Also, 00:01:00 is just the longer version of 00:01. Those are still the same underlying time

Comment: @Hooded0ne Thanks for the clarification. I quickly wrote some code to parse the data the way I want.